# Why is "différents" before the noun in the following sentence and also no articles used?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, articles, ordre-des-mots

(Ils ont participé à) différents événements historiques.
This sentence is from a text of a pretty good French podcast I have been using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'adjectif [différent](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/different) antéposé signifie *plusieurs*

La phrase pourrait s'écrire :

> (Ils ont participé à) *plusieurs* événements historiques.

---

> §B
>   2. Usuel, au plur. et antéposé avec valeur d'adj. indéf., exprimant la différence dans la pluralité.
>   a) [Le syntagme nom. est précédé de l'art. déf., qui marque qu'il est pris dans la totalité de son extension possible] Synon. certains, divers, plusieurs, variés.On y crie dans les rues [de Constantinople] les différents crus de fontaine (T'Serstevens, Itinér. esp.,1963, p. 259):

Comment: Merci beaucoup! En fait, j'ai déjà vu cette signification de "différents" quelque part, mais je l'ai oubliée cette fois. Il faut absolument que je passe plus de temps à apprendre Français.